# TensorFlow Deep Learning Model Training Error --- loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0000e+00

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I'm working on a sports analytics project to predict the outcome of MLB matchups with deep learning. When training the neural net with TensorFlow, I am getting 'NaN' for the loss and consistent 0's for the accuracy. Here is the full code for my model:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

matchups = pd.read_csv("data\\matchups\\model_matchups.csv", index_col=0)

y = matchups['outcome']
x_train = matchups.drop(columns=['outcome','game_code','batter_game_code','pitcher_game_code','batter_id','pitcher_id','b_pos'])

from sklearn import preprocessing

le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
le.fit(y)
labels_enc = le.transform(y)
labels = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(labels_enc)

ss = preprocessing.StandardScaler()
x_standardized = ss.fit_transform(x_train)
```

```
p = .1
inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input((74,), name='numeric_inputs')

x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(p)(inputs)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(500, activation='relu')(x)

x = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(p)(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(250, activation='relu')(x)

x = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(p)(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, activation='relu')(x)

x = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(p)(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(50, activation='relu')(x)

x = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
x = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(p)(x)
out = tf.keras.layers.Dense(55, activation='softmax', name='output')(x)

model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=out)
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

```
def bootstrap_sample_generator(batch_size):
    while True:
        batch_idx = np.random.choice(x_standardized.shape[0], batch_size)
        yield ({'numeric_inputs': x_standardized[batch_idx]},
               {'output': labels[batch_idx]})

batch_size = 128

model.fit(
    bootstrap_sample_generator(batch_size),
    steps_per_epoch=10_000 // batch_size,
    epochs=5,
    max_queue_size=10  
)
```

After researching this for a bit, it seems like this issue is commonly caused by incorrect model fitting for categorical data. I've attempted to resolve this by transforming the labels into one-hot vectors, but am still getting the training error.

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: The output layer of 55 jumps out at me right away. Why 55? What are you trying to predict?

Comment: are you trying to predict the win outcome of the team line for the year based on features stats of the previous year?  Is this the source of your data: https://www.retrosheet.org/schedule/index.html  (Date,GameNumber,DayOfWeek,VisitingTeam,VisitingLeague,HomeTeam,HomeLeague,SeasonGameNumber,TimeOfDay,Postponement,MakeupDate)

Comment: here is an article that explain how to use a neural network to predict the outcome of a basketball game based on momentum of the team.  https://towardsdatascience.com/attempting-to-predict-the-result-of-an-nba-game-before-you-could-finish-watching-the-first-half-4a1a97cfa31b

Comment: here is an article that explain how to use a neural network to predict the outcome of a basketball game based on momentum of the team.  https://towardsdatascience.com/attempting-to-predict-the-result-of-an-nba-game-before-you-could-finish-watching-the-first-half-4a1a97cfa31b  In this article he suggest using a svm instead of neural network and then focus on probability of momentum as an indicator of outcome

Comment: @chitown88 I'm trying to predict the outcome of a plate appearance. The data has one of 55 outcomes labelled for each record, which is why the output layer has 55 nodes

Comment: @GoldenLion I am using the retrosheet data for each plate appearance. I'm trying to predict the outcome of a batter-pitcher matchup. Thank you for the basketball article, I will be sure to check that out

Comment: And what’s category “0” mapped to?

Comment: You can try again by using the loss function `MeanSquaredError()` or `MeanAbsoluteError()`. Please have a look at this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/csv) for the reference.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone wondering, I forgot to remove null values from the training data.